# Are gas lines installed above fireplaces?

Tags: gas, fireplace, television

I am trying to install a TV above my fireplace (I know) and I hit something that looks like a metal pipe and I'm worried it's a gas pipe. Logically I assume no one would ever install a gas line above a fireplace because of combustion probabilities. I have no reason to think there'd be a gas line except for the fact that it's a fireplace and what the hell else would a small metal pipe be doing above a fireplace? There is no indication that it was ever a gas fireplace, there's a metal fire box inside the [image]fireplace but no gas line or knob. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you poke a hole? Do you smell gas? Could be conduit...

Comment: I can't smell gas. Do you mean the gas conduit from the main line to the fireplace? Or a conduit elsewhere? Would it be installed above the fireplace?

Comment: I doubt it is a gas line, but I couldn't say form here, nor am I a gas expert (not that kind), however, gas line is usually a thick walled steel, and not easy to puncture. If it was gas, you would have felt resistnce and stopped drilling, and then smelled gas. But could possibly be an electrical conduit. No gas smell, no wires inside? Your only other option is cut the wall and follow it. Or trace it somehow.

Comment: Does it really matter whether it's water, conduit or gas line? You don't want to drill into any of them. Just move the TV up or down a bit to avoid it.

Comment: In the UK there are often gas pipes above fireplaces because our houses are old enough to have been built with gas lighting. And some of those pipes are still live.